# Setting Up Kendo Basic Filtering Using DateFilter

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am following the filtering basics grid example from here: [Kendo Filtering Basics](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/filtering/). When I add the date filter component to the html page:

> ```
> <kendo-grid-date-filter-cell *ngSwitchCase="'date'"
>     [column]="column" [filter]="filter">
> </kendo-grid-date-filter-cell>
> ```

I get an error that the "kendo-grid-date-filter-cell" isn't an angular component.
This is what I have in my systemjs.config.js file for mapping the packages:

> ```
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-buttons',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-grid': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-l10n': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-l10n',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-popup': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-popup',
>     '@progress/kendo-popup-common': 'npm:@progress/kendo-popup-common',
>     '@progress/kendo-intl': 'npm:@progress/kendo-intl',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-intl': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-intl',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-inputs',
>     '@progress/kendo-data-query': 'npm:@progress/kendo-data-query',
>     '@progress/kendo-drawing': 'npm:@progress/kendo-drawing',
>     '@progress/kendo-file-saver': 'npm:@progress/kendo-file-saver',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export',
>     '@progress/kendo-ooxml': 'npm:@progress/kendo-ooxml',
>     '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs',
>     '@progress/kendo-date-math': 'npm:@progress/kendo-date-math',
> ```

```
    '@telerik/kendo-draggable': 'npm:@telerik/kendo-draggable',
    '@telerik/kendo-intl': 'npm:@telerik/kendo-intl',
    '@telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common': 'npm:@telerik/kendo-dropdowns-common',
    '@telerik/kendo-inputs-common': 'npm:@telerik/kendo-inputs-common'
```

and these are the packages in the package.json file:

> ```
> "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.24.1",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.0.1",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.39.9",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^0.1.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.27.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^0.23.5",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^0.12.0",
> "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^0.3.0",
> "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.5.3",
> "@progress/kendo-date-math": "^1.0.1",
> "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^0.15.6",
> ```

and these are the modules that I am importing to the project:

> ```
> import { GridModule, PDFModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
> import { ExcelExportModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export';
> import { DropDownListModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
> import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
> import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your grid version. Filtering was implemented pretty recently and you are using an older version. Most if not all Kendo component versions are up above 1.0 now.

Comment: Also, why are you doing a custom filter for a date filter?  If you just need to filter on date you should be able to add `[filter]="'date'"` into the `kendo-grid-column` and it will use the out of the box one.

Comment: Thanks yanbu, that's what I ended up doing. There is a business requirement that goes beyond what the basic date filter offers.